# Pytorch min and max of tensor

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I have following pytorch tensor:

```
>>> mean_actions
tensor([[-5.7547e-04,  1.4318e-02,  1.9328e-04, -2.5660e-03,  3.5269e-03,
         -1.3797e-02, -6.1871e-04, -2.7425e-03,  1.1661e-03,  1.6873e-03,
          3.9045e-03,  1.8047e-03,  4.8656e-03,  5.7182e-03, -4.8501e-03,
         -5.5913e-03, -4.4574e-03, -3.3154e-03, -4.9826e-03, -1.0071e-02,
         -2.3483e-03, -1.1413e-02, -4.9613e-03, -1.1648e-02,  2.4752e-03,
         -1.9764e-03,  3.1063e-03, -6.3481e-05,  7.6710e-03,  5.7503e-04]])
```

I am getting following min and max values out of tensor:

```
>>> th.min(mean_actions)
tensor(-0.0138)
>>> th.max(mean_actions)
tensor(0.0143)
```

However, I dont see `-0.0138` and `0.0143` present in the tensor. What I am missing?

Here are the screenshots from debug session:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.4318e-02 is scientific notation for 0.014318

and

-1.3797e-02 is scientific notation for -0.013797

See [Wikipedia - E Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)

Answer (score 3):

Both are there, it's in scientific notation. To get rid of scientific notation in pytorch use [`torch.set_printoption()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_printoptions.html)

```
>>> th = torch.tensor(([[-5.7547e-04,  1.4318e-02,  1.9328e-04, -2.5660e-03,  3.5269e-03,
...          -1.3797e-02, -6.1871e-04, -2.7425e-03,  1.1661e-03,  1.6873e-03,
...           3.9045e-03,  1.8047e-03,  4.8656e-03,  5.7182e-03, -4.8501e-03,
...          -5.5913e-03, -4.4574e-03, -3.3154e-03, -4.9826e-03, -1.0071e-02,
...          -2.3483e-03, -1.1413e-02, -4.9613e-03, -1.1648e-02,  2.4752e-03,
...          -1.9764e-03,  3.1063e-03, -6.3481e-05,  7.6710e-03,  5.7503e-04]]))
>>> th
tensor([[-5.7547e-04,  1.4318e-02,  1.9328e-04, -2.5660e-03,  3.5269e-03,
         -1.3797e-02, -6.1871e-04, -2.7425e-03,  1.1661e-03,  1.6873e-03,
          3.9045e-03,  1.8047e-03,  4.8656e-03,  5.7182e-03, -4.8501e-03,
         -5.5913e-03, -4.4574e-03, -3.3154e-03, -4.9826e-03, -1.0071e-02,
         -2.3483e-03, -1.1413e-02, -4.9613e-03, -1.1648e-02,  2.4752e-03,
         -1.9764e-03,  3.1063e-03, -6.3481e-05,  7.6710e-03,  5.7503e-04]])
>>> torch.set_printoptions(sci_mode=False)
>>> th
tensor([[    -0.0006,      0.0143,      0.0002,     -0.0026,      0.0035,
             -0.0138,     -0.0006,     -0.0027,      0.0012,      0.0017,
              0.0039,      0.0018,      0.0049,      0.0057,     -0.0049,
             -0.0056,     -0.0045,     -0.0033,     -0.0050,     -0.0101,
             -0.0023,     -0.0114,     -0.0050,     -0.0116,      0.0025,
             -0.0020,      0.0031,     -0.0001,      0.0077,      0.0006]])
```